# Centering standalone tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I'm wondering what is causing the following image to be so horribly off centred and how I might fix this issue (Note the massive space in the top left corner). Currently I am just post processing the .pdf. Code and resulting image are attached below

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
    \begin{document}

    % Define block styles
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=none, 
        text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=none, 
        text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \tikzstyle{butt} = [draw, ellipse,fill=none, node distance=3cm,
        minimum height=2em]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]

        % Place node
        \node [] (init) {};
        \node [right of=init, node distance=5cm] (system) {};
        \node [decision, below of=system, node distance=6cm] (triangle) {}; 
        \node [below of=init] (identify) {};
        \node [below of=identify] (evaluate) {};
        \node [left of=evaluate, node distance=5cm] (update) {};
        \node [block, below of=evaluate, node distance=5cm] (monitor) {Monitor Mode};
        \node [below of=monitor, node distance=5cm] (stop) {};
        \node [block, right of=monitor, node distance=8cm] (command) {Command Mode};
        \node [left of=monitor, node distance=3cm] (x) {};
        \node [below of=triangle, node distance=5.5cm] (nothing) {FRISTOP};
        \node [right of=monitor, below of=monitor, node distance=0.6cm] (a) {};
        \node [right of=monitor, above of=monitor, node distance=0.6cm] (b) {};
        % Draw edges     
        \path [line] (evaluate) -- node [near start]{FRIOPEN}(monitor);      
        \path [line] (monitor) -- node [near end]{FRICLOSE}(stop); 
        \path [line] (triangle) -| node [near start, black]{Timing In Sync}(command);
(monitor);
        \path [line] (x) -- node {Command}(monitor);
        \path [line] (x) -- node [below]{Error}(monitor);
        \draw [->] (command.south) |- ++(0,-2) -| (a);
        \path [line] (triangle) |- node [near end]{Quality Not Sufficient}(monitor);
        \path [line] (b) |- node [near start, right, black]{FRISTART}(triangle);
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Detecting the problem

By adding a `\frame` around the `tikzpicture`, you'll get a tight frame around the image that will show you what is really happening and where is the additional space; adding a little border to the `standalone` also helps:

```
    \documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
    \begin{document}

    % Define block styles
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=none, 
        text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=none, 
        text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \tikzstyle{butt} = [draw, ellipse,fill=none, node distance=3cm,
        minimum height=2em]

    \frame{\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]

        % Place node
        \node [] (init) {};
        \node [right of=init, node distance=5cm] (system) {};
        \node [decision, below of=system, node distance=6cm] (triangle) {}; 
        \node [below of=init] (identify) {};
        \node [below of=identify] (evaluate) {};
        \node [left of=evaluate, node distance=5cm] (update) {};
        \node [block, below of=evaluate, node distance=5cm] (monitor) {Monitor Mode};
        \node [below of=monitor, node distance=5cm] (stop) {};
        \node [block, right of=monitor, node distance=8cm] (command) {Command Mode};
        \node [left of=monitor, node distance=3cm] (x) {};
        \node [below of=triangle, node distance=5.5cm] (nothing) {FRISTOP};
        \node [right of=monitor, below of=monitor, node distance=0.6cm] (a) {};
        \node [right of=monitor, above of=monitor, node distance=0.6cm] (b) {};
        % Draw edges     
        \path [line] (evaluate) -- node [near start]{FRIOPEN}(monitor);      
        \path [line] (monitor) -- node [near end]{FRICLOSE}(stop); 
        \path [line] (triangle) -| node [near start, black]{Timing In Sync}(command);
(monitor);
        \path [line] (x) -- node {Command}(monitor);
        \path [line] (x) -- node [below]{Error}(monitor);
        \draw [->] (command.south) |- ++(0,-2) -| (a);
        \path [line] (triangle) |- node [near end]{Quality Not Sufficient}(monitor);
        \path [line] (b) |- node [near start, right, black]{FRISTART}(triangle);
    \end{tikzpicture}}


    \end{document}
```

This will produce

[image]

The image shows two main problems:

1. There is something *outside* the `tikzpicture` that is moving the image to the right.
2. There's something inside the image that is pushing the elements downwards and to the right.

## Finding the culprits

1. The only elements that might produce 1. above are the `\tikzstyles`.
2. Place some labels in the empty nodes to see what is realy going on:

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=none, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=none, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{butt} = [draw, ellipse,fill=none, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\frame{\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]

    % Place node
    \node [] (init) {Init};
    \node [right of=init, node distance=5cm] (system) {System};
    \node [decision, below of=system, node distance=6cm] (triangle) {}; 
    \node [below of=init] (identify) {Identify};
    \node [below of=identify] (evaluate) {Evaluate};
    \node [left of=evaluate, node distance=5cm] (update) {Update};
    \node [block, below of=evaluate, node distance=5cm] (monitor) {Monitor Mode};
    \node [below of=monitor, node distance=5cm] (stop) {};
    \node [block, right of=monitor, node distance=8cm] (command) {Command Mode};
    \node [left of=monitor, node distance=3cm] (x) {};
    \node [below of=triangle, node distance=5.5cm] (nothing) {FRISTOP};
    \node [right of=monitor, below of=monitor, node distance=0.6cm] (a) {};
    \node [right of=monitor, above of=monitor, node distance=0.6cm] (b) {};
    % Draw edges     
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- node [near start]{FRIOPEN}(monitor);      
    \path [line] (monitor) -- node [near end]{FRICLOSE}(stop); 
    \path [line] (triangle) -| node [near start, black]{Timing In Sync}(command);
(monitor);
    \path [line] (x) -- node {Command}(monitor);
    \path [line] (x) -- node [below]{Error}(monitor);
    \draw [->] (command.south) |- ++(0,-2) -| (a);
    \path [line] (triangle) |- node [near end]{Quality Not Sufficient}(monitor);
    \path [line] (b) |- node [near start, right, black]{FRISTART}(triangle);
\end{tikzpicture}}


\end{document}
```

The new result:

[image]

## A possible solution

As the previous analysys shows, there are two main problems with your code:

- You are using some nodes with no content that push the image downwards and to the right; those nodes are not really needed, so you can suppress them (see code below).
- Your `\tikzstyles` in the body of the document push the image to the right. Move them to the preamble (and change them to `\tikzset`; see code below).

Additional recommendations incorporated in the modified code below:

- Instead of the old, problematic, `of=` syntax, use the `=of` syntax from the `positioning` library.
- Instead of the old `\tikstyle`, use `\tikzset`.
- Your code can be simplified.

The new code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

% Define block styles
\tikzset{
  decision/.style={
    diamond, 
    draw, 
    text width=4.5em, 
    align=center,
    inner sep=0pt
    },
  block/.style={
    rectangle, 
    draw,
    text width=5em, 
    align=center, 
    rounded corners, 
    minimum height=4em
    },
  line/.style={draw, -latex'},
  butt/.style={
    draw, 
    ellipse,
    node distance=3cm,
  minimum height=2em
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
% Place node
\node[block] 
  (monitor) {Monitor Mode};
\node[block, right=5.5cm of monitor] 
  (command) {Command Mode};
\node[decision,above right=1cm and 3.5cm of monitor] 
  (tim) {};

% Draw edges 
\path[line] 
  (tim) -| 
    node[pos=0.4] {Timing in Sync}
  (command);  
\path[line] 
  (monitor) -- 
    node[near end] {FRICLOSE} 
  ++(0,-4cm); 
\path[line,<-] 
  (monitor) -- 
    node[near end,swap] {FRIOPEN} 
  ++(0,4cm); 
\path [line] 
  (monitor.60) |- 
    node[pos=0.4,swap] {FRISTART} 
  (tim); 
\path[line] 
  (tim) |- 
    node[near end] {Quality Not Sufficient} 
  (monitor); 
\path[line] 
  (command) |-
  ++(0,-2cm) -| 
    node[near start,swap] {FRISTOP} 
  (monitor.300); 
\path[line] 
  ([xshift=-2cm]monitor.west) --
    node {Command} 
    node[swap] {error} 
  (monitor); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have two phantom nodes that push the picture off :

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

    % Define block styles
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=none, 
        text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=none, 
        text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \tikzstyle{butt} = [draw, ellipse,fill=none, node distance=3cm,
        minimum height=2em]

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]

         Place node
        \node [] (init) {x};
        \node [right of=init, node distance=5cm] (system) {};
        \node [decision, below of=system, node distance=6cm] (triangle) {}; 
        \node [below of=init] (identify) {};
        \node [below of=identify] (evaluate) {};
        \node [left of=evaluate, node distance=5cm] (update) {y};
        \node [block, below of=evaluate, node distance=5cm] (monitor) {Monitor Mode};
        \node [below of=monitor, node distance=5cm] (stop) {};
        \node [block, right of=monitor, node distance=8cm] (command) {Command Mode};
        \node [left of=monitor, node distance=3cm] (x) {};
        \node [below of=triangle, node distance=5.5cm] (nothing) {FRISTOP};
        \node [right of=monitor, below of=monitor, node distance=0.6cm] (a) {};
        \node [right of=monitor, above of=monitor, node distance=0.6cm] (b) {};
%         Draw edges     
        \path [line] (evaluate) -- node [near start]{FRIOPEN}(monitor);      
        \path [line] (monitor) -- node [near end]{FRICLOSE}(stop); 
        \path [line] (triangle) -| node [near start, black]{Timing In Sync}(command);
(monitor);
        \path [line] (x) -- node {Command}(monitor);
        \path [line] (x) -- node [below]{Error}(monitor);
        \draw [->] (command.south) |- ++(0,-2) -| (a);
        \path [line] (triangle) |- node [near end]{Quality Not Sufficient}(monitor);
        \path [line] (b) |- node [near start, right, black]{FRISTART}(triangle);
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \end{document}
```